# Difference between mpl.pyplot.figure and mpl.figure.Figure

Tags: matplotlib, canvas, plot, tkinter, save

I have created a GUI based code for doing some calculations and plotting the output.

Currently, I am plotting my output graphs by embedding them into a canvas on the tkinter GUI, using matplotlib.figure.Figure. However, I need to open these graphs on a new window ALSO, so that they can be saved to use in reports etc.

I know that I can use matplotlib.pyplot.figure for this, but I need to do both - embed in canvas AND save the plot. And I have many plots that are embedded on the GUI. Which is the best way to do this?

Also, this could be a good opportunity for someone to explain the exact difference between these two objects. I could not find any satisfactory answer on the web. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just used matplotlib.pyplot.figure, and I could embed this on the canvas as well.